# MSP430FG4618 P2.4/UCA0TXD pin

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, uart, msp430

I need to connect the Sparkfun bluetooth module wire to the MSP430FG4618 P2.4 pin?

How do I locate that on the board? Is there a documentation to map the 2.4 to specific pins like H8 on the board?

Thank you

Comment: What board? MSP-TS430PZ100 or MSP-EXP430FG4618?

Comment: The MSP430-FG4618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the schematic on page 15 of the board's User's Guide, P2.4 is signal UCA0TXD, which is connected to the isolated RS-232 port. It is also available at pin 5 of H4.